# MVC website crashing at random locations only on live site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, web

I am developing a website using MVC.

I'm developing it with C# in Microsoft visual Studio 2010 and i'm using MVC4.

The site works correctly offline, but the online site has been acting strange.

Iv added logs to my online site so that i could track where there are errors.

I noticed that the site kept going down when downloading a file, but soon found after that the site would crash at random locations of code and some times pass the same sections of code.

So the info iv gotten of the logs are that the website goes down and random times.

I reverted my code to an older version where every thing was working fine but still get the random crashes at random places in my code.

There are no errors or exceptions thrown.

Could any one please tell me what could be the cause of this behaver?

Answer (score 0):

Add you using threads? When codes in threads throws an exception, it will crash the app pool and you won't get any details of the exception

Comment: Yes i use some threads for the download and tracking of download.

Comment: But the website goes down at random location's some times where threads are not involved.

Comment: I suppose you have logging in place. Do this, wrap the codes runs by the threads in a try/catch statement, then in the catch statement log the error. See if this still occurs.

Comment: is that anything in your event log? Can  you post your threading code and the code where it crashes?